# Kubernetes - NginxIngressController resources not creating

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, nginx-ingress

We are using Nginx ingress operator version 0.2.0 and the controller version 1.11.1. Following steps are completed to deploy the CRD and operator.
https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ingress-operator/blob/release-0.2.0/docs/manual-installation.md

After that, we are deploying the controller using the following yaml:

```
apiVersion: k8s.nginx.org/v1alpha1
kind: NginxIngressController
metadata:
  name: nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  type: deployment
  image:
    repository: nginx/nginx-ingress
    tag: 1.11.1
    pullPolicy: Always
  serviceType: NodePort
  nginxPlus: False
```

The manifest gets applied successfully but none of the required resources are getting created (deployment and service). Hence, the ingress is not getting the address.

```
kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx
No resources found in ingress-nginx namespace.
```

```
kubectl get ing
NAME              CLASS    HOSTS   ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
my-ingress        <none>   *                 80      6h23m
```

kubeadm, kubelet & kubectl version 1.21.2.

Earlier we had deployed it on minikube and it was working fine.

Comment: Have you created the namespace (ingress-nginx). If you have created then can you check with this command whether the namespace is there or not:

$ kubectl get namespace

Comment: yes, the namespace is created otherwise kubectl apply would fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have reproduced the use case using Nginx ingress operator version 0.4.0 and the controller version 2.0.x by following the [documentation](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-ingress-operator) and successfully created the Nginx Ingress Operator and NginxIngressController. Firstly, I didn't create the namespace **ingress-nginx**,While running the command
**kubectl get all -n ingress-nginx**.  I was getting the error **No resources found in ingress-nginx namespace**.

[image]

After creating the required namespace by running the command **kubectl create namespace ingress-nginx**   ,  I am able to get the resources(pod,service,deployment,replica set) successfully.

[image]

[image]

Can you try again by changing the nginx controller and operator versions to the latest one and also check the configurations correctly.

Comment: Thanks, Bakul! We also eventually moved to v0.4.0 which helped us resolve the issues with the controller and the operator. Lastly, we were missing an ingress class annotation in the Ingress class.